# How to send one-off query with Relay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm trying to send a one-off query using Relay. So, I don't necessarily want to use `QueryRenderer` but rather have a simple API to send a query without binding the result to a React component.

Previously, this was possible with the `fetch` method on `network`:

```
const checkVoteQueryText = `
  query CheckVoteQuery($userId: ID!, $linkId: ID!) {
    viewer {
      allVotes(filter: {
        user: { id: $userId },
        link: { id: $linkId }
      }) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`
const checkVoteQuery = { text: checkVoteQueryText }
const result = await this.props.relay.environment._network.fetch(checkVoteQuery, {userId, linkId})
```

It seems however that `fetch` has been deprecated in some newer version of Relay. Is there an alternative that can be used now?

If Relay doesn't allow for one-off queries, I'd probably just `graphql-request` or plain JS fetch to get the job done. But it would be nice to be able to use Relay for this as it already knows my endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah this was actually rather simple to achieve. In fact, calling `fetch` on `this.props.relay.environment._network` only reused the function that's passed into the `Network` when it's created. So, it's possible to just reuse this function, in my case it's called `fetchQuery`:

#### `Environment.js`

```
import {GC_AUTH_TOKEN} from './constants'
import { SubscriptionClient } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws'

const {
  Environment,
  Network,
  RecordSource,
  Store,
} = require('relay-runtime')

const store = new Store(new RecordSource())

// Export it here so it can be reused in other files
export const fetchQuery = (operation, variables) => {
  return fetch('https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cj9h5g99s24fb0100nsp81d4y', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(GC_AUTH_TOKEN)}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: operation.text,
      variables,
    }),
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
}

const network = Network.create(fetchQuery)

const environment = new Environment({
  network,
  store,
})

export default environm
```

ent